# Request timed out error exporting to excel in Nop Commerce?

Tags: c#, nopcommerce

**When I attempt to export more then 5000 products to an excel file, I get this error.**

**Description**: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details:

> System.Web.HttpException: Request timed out

Comment: What's the version of nopcommerce?

Comment: @Nahid I'm using NopCommerce Version  3.80

Comment: Use this.  
Hope it might help.
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime executionTimeout="180" />
</system.web>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This worked for me :**

```
 <system.web>
   <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" enableVersionHeader="false" 
     maxRequestLength="1048576000" requestLengthDiskThreshold="8192" 
     executionTimeout="180" />
 </system.web>
```